# how to use global laravel command in .sh file?

Tags: laravel, bash, ubuntu

I'm just writing a custom script to create a new Apache 2 virtualhost with automatical installation of a new laravel project.

I had already setted up composer's vendors path to global PATH, so when I enter `laravel new blog` directly into terminal, everything works fine.

But when I call it from my bash script (sudo bash new_laravel_vhost.sh)

```
...
if [ ! -d "$absolute_doc_root" ]; then
  cd "$web_root/"
  laravel new $site_url
fi
...
```

it echoes to me, that **laravel: command not found**. Do you know any way how to make it work? Why it is not working?

Comment: Are you sure it's executed by the same user? What is the output with `sudo laravel new $site_url`?

Comment: if you run as sudo, `sudo laravel new blog`, it works fine too? Other questions suggests that maybe its end of the line problem, with blank lines. you can check on the editor if this is your case too

Comment: Oh, no, it is not working. *sudo: laravel: command not found*